# Limit /home size per user

Tags: linux, user, quota

I'm doing a college project in which I have several groups of users. One of those groups is developers, which have a special condition, they have access to their Workspace (which is located inside /home) where they have a limited amount of space to store their files.

Additionally there are 2 partitions mounted on /svn and /web.

The thing is I've come to two solutions:

- Using limits.conf allows me to set a hard limit on the data of every user I want. So I can limit the size of each developer to XGB. The problem with this solution is that the users would have their amount of space limited when creating files in the /svn directory (which shouldn't happen).
- On the other side, I could create an extra partition which would be mounted in the /home or in other /whatever directory and making that file system the /home of the developers. That would solve the problem with /svn due to being able to use quota on that file system. But I'm not quite sure if I like separating the developers from the rest of the users.

Is there a way of limiting the amount of space per user per directory without using quota or a different file system? Or is there any better solution I could use?

Answer (score 1):

Use LVM2. You can create as many volumes as you like, set diskquotas without reserving the diskspace beforehand and much more.

Plus it supports encrypted partitions, a nice addition to you college project.

It is relatively simple once you understand how LVM works.